# What are these people doing in these transparent balls?

Tags: star-wars, andor

In the opening scene of *Andor*, Cassian walks past some people in strange transparent balls.

What were they doing? It kind of looked like something recreational but I can't say anything for sure.

[image]

Comment: Recreational indeed.

Comment: Ballers be ballin’

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Those are (alien) prostitutes. The episode's audio description makes it abundantly clear that they're 'on display' and given that this is the ['Leisure Zone'](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Leisure_Zone), it doesn't seem likely to be a zoo.

> *"Transparent plastic bubbles protrude from the buildings on either side, displaying aliens who react to Cassian as he passes on his way down a set of stairs"*

You may recall seeing something similar in the city of Amsterdam on a planet called Earth.

[image]

Comment: Lol. I was trying to work out how to fit a "maybe a heavy petting zoo" joke into my answer without it being too sleazy

Comment: Andor season 2 should be set in Amsterdam